# Check status on the server with specific port

Tags: c#, .net, client, server, status

I need check status of any computers in my local network. But my code isn't effective, because in there is very long response. I tried threads, that checker runs on background. But i need have a faster check. My program runs as client-server.

On my main program i need write available computers to *listbox*. 
Example:

My main client wants get available computers in local network. Computers have a server runs on port **13000**. But, when I want find out available computers, in there is too long response.

**Variables**

```
string message = "!";
string temp = "";
public static string list = "";
```

**Checker available computers:**

```
public static void checker()
    {
        string IP;
        int statResp = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {              
            IP = "192.168.0." + i;

            string msg = "!";

            try
            {
                Int32 port = 13000;

                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, port);


                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                msg = "!";


                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                data = new Byte[256];
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                if (responseData == " " || responseData == "!")
                {
                    statResp = 1; // response is correct server runs
                }
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                continue; // continue with next iteration
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
              continue; // continue with next iteration
            }
            if (statResp == 1)
            {
                list = IP; // list is variable
            }
        } 
    }
```

**TIMER - Checking data in *list* variable**

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (temp != list)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(list);
            temp = list;
        }
    }
```

If **list** variable have a same value as in **temp** variable, old address will not be added to list.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. When I will send UDP broadcast packet to UDP listener (client), sender's IP address will be transmitted to sending new packet to last sender. Original sender (server) will receive new IP address from remote client.